# Set a class to access variables from timeline in AS3?

Tags: class, actionscript-3, variables

I learned recently that putting `MovieClip(root).` in front of my variables in a class will allow me to call upon variables set in the timeline. However, having a large amount of need to call upon different variables makes this a daunting task. Is there anyway to set a class to call on the root instead of its own directory? So I dont have to add `MovieClip(root).` in front of every single variable? I have no need to create new variables in my class file.

Comment: That depends on the nature of you class.  What is the context of your class in relation to the main timeline?

Comment: Welcome to OOP. There's no global scope here except class definitions. You probably need not a way to address **root** but a class for shared data.